# How to disable Case Notification Email

Tags: email, case, notification

I noticed that there's a standard email case notification that's being sent whenever a case is assigned to an owner, case comment is created, or email is sent via send an email button. However, we don't need these. Is there a way to deactivate these emails from being sent out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's found in Setup > Customize > Cases > Support Settings. The "Notify Case Owners when Case Ownership Changes" controls ownership notifications, and "Notify Case Owner of New Case Comments" is for new case comments. The emails sent when a user sends an email is in their personal setup menu (Name > My Settings > Email > My Email Settings). Note that users still have an option to send an email by checking the box. For API updates, set the EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail flag to false to prevent notifications.

Comment: Thanks! so Notify Case Owners when Case Ownership Changes is triggered on newly created cases as well? Also I don't see how I can configure the New Email for Case Notification on My Email Settings

Comment: @sforce That depends on the new case. Generally speaking, you'll find that in your Assignment Rule (see Setup > Customize > Cases > Assignment Rules), or "Notify Default Case Owner" for automated cases from external sources (same page as as mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Notify Default Case Owner is not activated as well as assignment rules

Comment: @sforce What's the email template look like? There's so many ways to notify users, it's really hard to think of everything.

Comment: we actually want to disable all email notifications. thats why we didnt setup any. "An email has been received for Case <case number>: <case subject>. Please click the link below to review the new email and respond appropriately." I cant find the email template for this as well

Comment: @sforce Setup > Customize > Cases > Email-to-Case? Notify Case Owners On New Email?

Comment: @sforce I'm glad we found it. I was starting to run out of ideas.